# UrlDecode value on html textbox on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple form with three fields that I need to submit to an mvc action. The form must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. however, one of the fields is populated by users copying and pasting an already urlencoded value. I would like to decode that value prior to submitting the form. this seems really simple but I keep running into proplems with my javascript.

Here is the code:

```
   <html>
    <head>
<script>
function decodeURI()
{
decodeURIComponent(document.createprofile.URI.value);
}
</script>
    <title>Test Create</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <h1> Spoof Profile Calls </h1>
    <hr>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
    <b>Create</b>
    <form method="post" action="https://test.test-lab.com/Profile/Create/" name="createprofile">
    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURL" value="self.close()">
    UserName: <input type="text" name="UserName"><br />
    Client: <input type="text" name="Client"><br />
    URI: <input type="text" name="URI" onblur="decodeURI();"><br />
    <input type="submit" formenctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" value="Go To - Create"><br />
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The URI field is the one that needs url decoded prior to submission because it gets reencoded and thus corrupted. I could ask the users to un-encode these values themselves but they are not terribly sophisticated users and it will likely not happen.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATED WITH FAILING CODE**

Comment: Hi you can use, onChange listerner of that textfield and change the value of that textfield using the javascript.

Comment: I tried something like that but received an error saying "cannot read property 'value' or undefined" maybe you could help me with the javascript?

Comment: can you post the code what have you tried /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line

```
URI: <input type="text" name="URI" onblur="decodeURI();"><br />
```

by

```
URI: <input type="text" name="URI" onchange="decodeURI(this);"><br />
```

And do something like

```
function decodeURI(elm) {
    elm.value = 'foo ' + elm.value + ' bar';
    return false;
}
```